# Apple and private APIs

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi

Now that it's public knowledge that App Store submissions are being tested for use of private APIs, I need to ask the question... what exactly is a private API so that I may avoid them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A private API is an API that is not documented in the SDK. For instance, a framework class might declare a method that is not intended to be used by outside developers. The behavior of a private API is not guaranteed. You can't even be sure that the method will be there in the future updates of the platform. Its declaration is probably not available in publicly distributed SDK header files. If you stick to things publicly defined in the SDK documentation, you'll be OK.

Comment: So rather than calling a method within a private API, what's the difference of you creating your own method that does the same thing? Am I correct in saying that it's not the issue of calling certain API methods, it's the fact that you're trying to do things they don't want you to do?

Comment: @Nick Not necessarily. For an app to get approved by Apple, you should have both of the following: 1. only do things that they haven't restricted you from, regardless of the method. 2. do them through a valid mechanism. There can be things that are okay to do in general, but you cannot call a private API directly to accomplish them. The ritual is a private API may change in future versions and breaks your app, whereas writing a custom method on a public API is not supposed to break with an iOS upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

You will find it difficult to use a private API by accident. They are not documented within the SDK docs, and they don't show up in XCode's code completion suggestions.

The reason this has become news recently is the creator of a framework used by several apps used a private API, so when developers who included his framework updated their apps, they were rejected (even though THOSE developers didn't use a private API, the framework they added to their application did).

That's about the only way you could possibly use a private API accidentally.

Comment: It was in the three20 framework, but the problem has been long since remedied. This answer is over two years old.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just private APIs that can cause your application to get rejected. Using undocumented members of a public API can cause your application to get rejected. For example, the three20 library (since fixed) accessed _phase and other members of UITouch within a category.

They can also detect calls to *private* members via performSelector, as the following also flagged a rejection:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow]
return !![window performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
```

More disturbing, if you make your application work under 3.1 and 3.0 and at runtime in 3.0 you don't use any of 3.1 stuff your application can still get rejected. An example might be  the `cameraOverlayView` of `UIImagePickerController` (see [here](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/yet-another-dubious-app-rejection-story/)). This is kind of puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Generally by their absence from SDK headers. One of apple's conventions is to lead ObjC method names with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

A great tool to use before you submit your app is App Scanner.  It scans your .app file for private API usage and shows you what method signatures match up and what classes those methods are in.

link --> http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/

Comment: Looks like this site is either down. Anyone know of any other apps that perform similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

My app was rejected by apple because of using private API.Here is code,

```
    Class UIKeyboardImpl = NSClassFromString(@"UIKeyboardImpl");

    id activeInstance = [UIKeyboardImpl performSelector:@selector(activeInstance)];

    [activeInstance performSelector:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to get rejected by so called "using private API". Try to use the following as Core Data attribute and it would be rejected:

- colorIndex
- occurrence
- id

It shows how the robot scans the API.