# Programmatically change silent on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

So I've been wondering if it's possible to programmatically disable/enable the silencer (controlled by the silent switch on the side of the iPhone)? According to lots of researching, this is supposedly impossible due to Apple rejecting it, and there really not being a way to do it in the first place. The only way I can possibly think of would be to use the celestial.framework, but that's private and I can't get it to import without a trillion annoying errors that I don't understand. I did download an app called AutoSilent that somehow manages to do this though. I tested it, and it works just as advertised. How in the world are they able to manipulate the silent function? Here's the app: [AutoSilent](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8%22%5Dhttps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8)

Comment: My guess is that these guys are using private APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580251/what-exactly-is-a-private-api-and-why-will-apple-reject-an-ios-app-if-one-is-us