# Apple App guidelines - is a GET and POST request a private API?

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

My IOS app transfers data to/from my web server using GET and POST queries. Are these 'third party API's or private APIs, and disallowed?  I am a beginner, and would like clarification on these definitions? My app purpose is to submit site user's votes to a website, so I am using a POST query to post the data to my server, and a GET query to confirm the user's login is valid.

Comment: No, I don't think "Private API" in Applespeak ever applies to talking to a server on the web (which pretty much every app does). Here's an answer on what "private API" means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773615/apple-and-private-apis Something that you want to be aware of when connecting to web servers is that starting next year, any traffic you do from your app needs to be HTTPS. https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/

Comment: great,  I have https too. Thank you- that is a relief